# Adding new kernel to VirtualBox to solve "Kernel panic"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, virtualbox, kernel-panic

I am using VirtualBox on my MacOS with the following version of ubuntu:ubuntu-22.04.1.
When I launch this on VirtualBox, I receive the following:
[image]

What should I do and how can I add another kernel to this virtualbox?

Comment: Is this when you boot from the ISO?

Comment: ... or did this occur after upgrading an established virtual machine?

Comment: This was when I booted from an ISO.

Comment: a "new" kernel won't help then, since an ISO is technically a read only medium

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I've got the same issue with a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.2 ISO and VBox 6.1.28